# System.InvalidOperationException in my c# project

Tags: c#, oop

my project is about a class Account and 2 child classes (current account and deposit account).

in the main I created an arraylist of accounts
but I'm trying to delete an object in this method:

```
    public static void Remove(ArrayList L, int accnb)
    {
        foreach(Account obj in L)
        {
            if(obj.AccN == accnb)
                L.Remove(obj);
        }
    }
```

but I got an error : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

all other methods like add or return string worked fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't remove elements while iterating over the collection with a `foreach`.

Also, I'd recommend using `List<T>` rather than `ArrayList`.

An easier way to solve the task at hand is to simply do:

```
public static void Remove(List<Account> L, int accnb) => 
                            L.RemoveAll(obj => obj.AccN == accnb);
```

Answer (score 0):

The items in an `ArrayList` are typed as `object`. Therefore, C# does not know that they have a member named `AccN`.

There is a strongly typed, generic equivalent of `ArrayList` named `List<T>`. Here you specify the type of the list items explicitly when you create the list with

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
```

This list can also contain objects of the derived classes `CurrentAccount` and `DepositAccount`. Use it like this

```
public static void Remove(List<Account> L, int accnb)
{
    foreach(Account acc in L)
    {
        if(acc.AccN == accnb)
            L.Remove(acc);
    }
}
```

Note: in C# 1.0 and C# 1.1 there were no generics. Therefore, the weakly typed collection `ArrayList` was implemented. Since generics were introduced in C# 2.0, this type is mostly obsolete.

With `ArrayList` you would have to cast the object to the right type to make it work

```
if(((Account)acc).AccN == accnb)
```

---

You also have another problem. You cannot change the very collection you are enumerating with `foreach`, because this confuses `foreach`. Use a for-loop instead and make sure you loop in reverse order to not change the indexes of the items ahead when removing items.

```
for (int i = L.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (L[i].AccN == accnb) {
        L.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

The [C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) says:

> The `foreach` statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for loop.

Comment: aah okk cause List doesn't work,  I got an error The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Add a `using System.Collections.Generic` at the top of your code or use the light bulb which does it for you.

Comment: it doesn't work :/ I try the answer above u it worked but its new for me

Comment: Most probably the problem is that you are modifying the collection in `foreach`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

foreach does not actually work with collections, but with [Enumerators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx). While all collections are implicitly convertable into a Enumerator, Enumeartor rules still apply.

So basically your code is interpreted as:

```html
temp IEnumerator = L.GetEnumerator();
foreach(Account obj in temp)
```

All enumerators have the rule that you **can not** change the underlying collection. Doing so will (has to) invalidate the enumerator. Wich will throw said except the next call of .Current().

As you can not change the collections while using a enumerator and foreach uses only Enumerators below the hood, that means you can not change the colelciton (inlcuding removing elements) while using foreach. You need one of the much more wordy loops to do this.